# How to enhance length of Property of an attribute of class in eco Model designer

Tags: mdriven

Iam using mdriven build 7.0.0.11347 for DDD project and have model designed in .ecomdl file.

In this file i have a class Job with WorkDone as one of a property. Backedup SQL table has WorkDone varchar(255) field. Now i wanted to increase length of this field and When i changed the WorkDone property length from 255 to 2000 then it modified the code file but when application runs EvolveSchema then evolving process doesn't recognize this change which leads to no scripts being generated. In the end database doesn't get this updated.

Can you please help me how to get this change persist to database.  I thought to increase manually to SQL table but then if database gets change in case of new envrionment QA production then it has to be done every time, which id don't want to do.

Comment: Change it from varchar to text/blob - varchar can only do 255 chars, where others can go a LOT higher

Comment: May be i couldn't clarify. Schema change or type change has to be done via Code (i.e. ecomdl file ) and not via SQL, because Job and its field are autogenerated by the .ecomdl file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MDriven we dont evolve attribute changes - we only write a warning (255->2000 this change will not be evolved)
You should take steps to alter the column in the database yourself.

- We should fix in the future but currently this is a limitation

Comment: Thanks Hans!. Will look forward for this update

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, `VARCHAR` can only be from 0-255 chars

Using `TEXT` will allow for non-binary (character) strings and `BLOB`s will allow for binary (byte) strings

Your mileage may vary with this as to what you can do with them, as I am using MySQL knowledge and knowledgebases (since you don't specify your SQL type)

See below for exaplanations of the types;

- [char / varchar](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html)
- [blobs / text](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)